# Develop equivalence relations among pairs of strings

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph-theory, adjacency-list, equivalence-classes

I have a set of <string, string> pairs which represents equivalency among them:
[(“Player1”, “Player2”), (“Player3”, “Player4”), (“Player2”, “Player3”), (“Player11”, “Player13”)]

This means, “Player1” is equivalent to “Player2” and “Player3” is equivalent to “Player4” and so on. Basically all players with relations belong to a same team.

Then I have Scores also in a set as <string, int> pairs.
[(“Player1”, 50), (“Player3”, 25)]

I want to find out he total score of Player1's team. (which would be 75 in this case)

My idea is to develop a bidirectional graph relation among pairs from the equivalency pairs like:
Player1<--->Player2<--->Player3<--->Player4 and mark them under a similar id or enum

So that when I want to get the total score of Player1's team, I can get the scores of other players related to Player1 and sum them up.

Below is the interface design I can imagine:

```
void buildRelations(vector<pair<string, string>> equivalances) {
// make some data scructure to store the relations:
// Player1<--->Player2<--->Player3<--->Player4 (team1)
// Player11<--->Player13 (team2)
}

int getTotalTeamScore(string player) {
// If Player1 is passed, the return should be 50 + 25 as Player 3 belongs to Playes1's team
}
```

I found related articles, which seems interesting but can't fire out how I design the data structure to store the relations and search related players to sum their scores.
[1] [Enumerating equivalence classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66819455/enumerating-equivalence-classes)
[2] [DFS implementation in c++ using adjacency list (using <vector> and linked list)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39708305/dfs-implementation-in-c-using-adjacency-list-using-vector-and-linked-list)

It would be great if someone can help me to understand and develop the data structure.

Comment: There are some different ways to do this, but I'd consider building a container of containers where each sub-container lists the players on one team, instead of directly storing and then traversing the given relations. The conversion isn't too bad, but notice in your example's order it would have {{P1, P2}, {P3, P4}}, and then on processing {P2, P3}, realize those two teams are really the same team and merge them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to bother with a graph. A map will do the job

Declare a structure for the players.

```
struct sPlayer 
{
    string name;
    int score;
    vector< string > eqivalency;
};
```

Declare a map for the relationships

```
 map< string, sPlayer > mpPlayer;
```

Now write code to implement:

```
- read the scores, inserting the player name and score into the map
- read the equivalencies, updating the map with the equivalencies
- input a player
- look up the player in the map
- LOOP over the player's equivalencies
   - Sum the scores of the equivalent players
- Add player score to sum
```

Comment: making sPlayer a class with APIs like update() the whole implementation became a cakewalk. Thanks for the eye opener.. I was thinking in a very complicated direction with no result.

Comment: Actually with the abode Data Structure we are making a directed graph, to read to the equivalences, I have to run BFS or DFS (recursive).